# ObservableList clear method not removing items for garbage collection (gc) JavaFX 2.2

Tags: java, garbage-collection, javafx-2, javafx, tabpage

I have a TabPane where a lot of Tab's will be open and close. When the number of this Tabs are going to ~200, i get a Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. The number 200 is the total tabs that was opened. For example the 180 of them could be opened and then closed - i use the tabpane.getTabs().remove(tabObject) method - and the 20 could be active. The same error is produced even if i use the clear method for removing all of the tabs.
I am using for debugging the Visual VM software and i see that even if i remove or clear the tabs, they are not garbage collected.
Is this a bug or there is another way of removing tabs(items) from a tabpane(ObservableList)?

Comment: If they are not garbage-collected even after you explicitly make it collect the garbage a few times (Debbugger/Profile should handle that), then there must be some references to those tabs somewhere.

Comment: Are you binding those tabs' properties to some other properties? Remove property bindings, added event handlers as well.

Comment: The strange think is that i am not binding any properties of the Tabs and i don't have any inner classes and i don't have any listeners for the Tabs. I think that the only existing reference is the one of the TabPane.

Answer (score 0):

because reference of added element is bind with other mostly with the scene is attached with observable list items